# Laravel query multiple tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Using Laravel 5.3, I have a database consisting of users, products and wishlists joined bya a pivot table product_wishlist. The schema is below:

```
USERS          WISHLISTS     PRODUCTS        PRODUCT_WISHLIST
-------------  -------------  --------------  ---------------
id             id             id              product_id
name           name           name            wishlist_id
               user_id
```

In App/Wishlist.php

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_wishlist');
}

public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In App/product.php

```
public function wishlists()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Whishlist::class, 'product_wishlist');
}
```

A user can create wishlists and add products to wishlists.

In a product page, I'm trying show all wishlists of logged user.

```
$wishlists = Auth::user()->wishlists;
```

But i also want retrive if each wishlist contains the product (i will add a "add to wishlist" button near of each wishlist only if this not contains the product yet).

I edit after the Kabelo answer:

What i want is show a single product page, and in the sidebar shows all wishlists of the logged user (each user has your own wishlists): wishlist1 (add to list), wishlist2 (add to list),... but if for example the product of this page is already in the wishlist2 then no show "(add to list)". In these cases I could show "(remove from list)"

Comment: You are missing a relationship between whitelist and product. With that you just do something like `$user->wishlist->products...` and of course you can count them and make checks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A user can create **wishlists** and add products to wishlists.

From your question, I see a user can create multiple wishlists, here's a way to achieve that.

In App/Wishlist.php

```
class Wishlist extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the products for the wishlist.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_wishlist');
    }

    /**
    * Get owner/creator of wishlist.
    */
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

In App/Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the wishlists for the product.
     */
    public function wishlists()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Wishlist', 'product_wishlist');
    }

}
```

In Controller function

```
$products = App\Products::with(['wishlist'=> function($query){
    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}])->get();
return view('product.index', compact('products'))
```

In views/product/index.blade.php

```
@foreach( $products as $product )

    <div class="product">
        <h3>{{ $product->name }}</h3>
        @if( ! count($product->wishlists) )
            <button>Add to wishlist</button>
        @endif
    </div>

@endforeach
```

> To show on **single product page**

In Controller

```
public function show($id){
    $_product = App\Products::where('id', $id)->first();
    $wishlists = null;
    $product_is_in_wishlist = false;
    if(Auth::check()){
        $wishlists = App\Wishlists::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
            ->with('products')->get();
        foreach( $wishlists as $wishlist ){
            if( $wishlist->products->where('id', $_product->id)->count() ){
                $product_is_in_wishlist= true;
            }
        }
    }

    return view('product.show', compact('_product', 'wishlists', 'product_is_in_wishlist'));
}
```

In view/product/show.blade.php

```
<div id='product_container'>
    <h1>{{ $_product->name }}</h1>
    @if( $product_is_in_wishlist )
        <button>Remove from wishlist</button>
    @else
        <button>Add to wishlist</button>
    @endif
</div>
<div id='wishlists_sidebar'>
    <ul>
        @foreach( $wishlists as $wishlist)
            <li>{{ $wishlist->name }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Kabelo. What i want is show a single product page, and in the sidebar shows all wishlists of the logged user (each user has your own wishlists): wishlist1 (add to list), wishlist2 (add to list),... but if for example the product of this page is already in the wishlist2 then no show "(add to list)". In these cases I could show "(remove from list)"

Comment: I just made added the 'add to wishlist' button logic. Let me know ho it goes.

Comment: works great thank you! I replaced `if( $wishlist->products->where('id', $_product->id) )` with `if( $wishlist->products->where('id', $_product->id)->count() )`